# Get database ID and put it in on clickview on ListView

Tags: android

I get data from database (id, name) and I  display (name) in a ListView. When user clicks I need to get database (id) to perform an action

KoiskesdataActivity.java

```
package koisk.data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


public class KoiskesdataActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     ProgressDialog pd;
     private ListView koisksListView;
     private EditText myfilter;
    // private ArrayAdapter <String> koiskarrayAdapter;
      String koiskArray[];
     Button autocompletekoisksname;
     int textlength=0;
     private ArrayList<String> array_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ///
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        ///
        koisksListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.koiskslist);
         myfilter=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
         ///////
         pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
         pd.setMessage("loading...");
         pd.show();
         /////
       getarrayofnamekoisk namekoisk=new getarrayofnamekoisk();

        koiskArray=namekoisk.WW();


       ArrayAdapter <String> koiskarrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter <String>(KoiskesdataActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,koiskArray);
       koisksListView.setAdapter(koiskarrayAdapter);
       pd.dismiss();
       koisksListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

        myfilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
            {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    textlength = myfilter.getText().length();
                    array_sort.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < koiskArray.length; i++)

                        {
                            if (textlength <= koiskArray[i].length())
                            {
                                //subSequence returns the specified word between the begien and end 
                                //equalsIgnoreCase  compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations. Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length, and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case
                                if (myfilter.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String)koiskArray[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
                                    {
                                    array_sort.add(koiskArray[i]);
                                    }
                            }
                        }

                        //KoiskesdataActivity.this.koiskarrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);

                        koisksListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(KoiskesdataActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array_sort));


            }
        });

    }

}
```

getarrayofnamekoisk.java

```
    package koisk.data;


import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.transform.Templates;

import android.R.array;
import android.R.integer;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class getarrayofnamekoisk{
    private int i;
    private String[] koiskname ;
    private int num_rows;
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapterdata;

    List<String[]> names = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();



    public String[] WW()  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        connecttodatabase qq=new connecttodatabase();
        qq.dbconnect();
        if (qq.con !=null)
        {
            try
            {
            Statement st = qq.con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT Name,id FROM Device where DeviceTypeId=4 and IsDeleted =0 and name is not null ");
               while(rs.next())
               {

                   arr.add(rs.getString("name"));
               }
                koiskname= new String [arr.size()];

                arr.toArray(koiskname);

                }


             catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(ConnectbyprocedureActivity.this,  e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                }
            qq.closeConnection();
        }

        return koiskname;
    }

    }
```

connecttodatabase.java //to connect to sql server

```
package koisk.data;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class connecttodatabase {
    public java.sql.Connection  con = null;
     private final String userName="sa"; 
     private final String pass="123"; 
     /////////
     private final String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://";
    private final String serverName= "192.168.1.200";
    private final String portNumber = "1433";
    private final String databaseName= "loadshedding";
     ////////////

    /**
     * @param args
     */
     private String getConnectionUrl(){
        //jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.200:1433/loadShedding
        //return url+serverName+":"+portNumber+";databaseName="+databaseName+";selectMethod="+selectMethod+";";
        return url+serverName+":"+portNumber+"/"+databaseName;
   }
     public java.sql.Connection dbconnect() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
        //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        //jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.200:1433/loadShedding
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl(), userName, pass);


       //    if(con!=null) System.out.println("Connection Successful!");
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      //     tv.setText(e.toString());
       }  

        return con ;
    }
//   public void displayDb(){
//       java.sql.DatabaseMetaData dm = null;
    //   java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
    //   try{
    //       con=this.dbConnect();

    //   }
    //   catch(Exception e){
    //        e.printStackTrace();
     //  }

    // }


    public void closeConnection(){
        try{
             if(con!=null)
                  con.close();
             con=null;
        }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }     
}
```

please i need help ..... thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the `id` from the database, but you never store it anywhere.. you first need to store it in an `Array` or `ArrayList` (lets say, `idList`). You have to do it similar to how you store the names in a list. then:

You can get the position of the item which is clicked inside the `onItemClick` method as 
follows:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,  long arg3) {
    int position = arg2;
    clickedID = idList.get(position);
    // do something with the clicked id.
}
```